# Can multiple download locations be defined in the SRC_URI for a BB recipe?

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

What I'm trying to do is define a secondary location for a file (http://) or repo (git://) in the SRC_URI if the first one happens to fail.

Something like:

```
SRC_URI = "http://site1/mytar.tar.gz \
           http://site2/mytar.tar.gz \
```

or

```
SRC_URI = "git://site1/myrepo.git \
           git://site2/myrepo.git
```

Where if the first one fails, it will try the second option and not just download them both over each other.

I know there are pre-mirrors, local cache, and mirrors, but I really just want to specify multiple locations in the BB recipe.

This seems like something that should be supported, but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not supported.  The developers designed the mirroring scheme for that use case.  In your example, the fetcher will try to download *both* files.  Sorry, but that's the way it works today.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it would be easier to help here if you say *what* the cause of "happens to fail" is.  If it's "remote site is intermittently offline" then the mirror support is exactly the solution you're after.  If it's something else then please explain the problem you're having.